# Child nodes to comma delimited string with Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<node1>
 <item>hello</item>
 <item>world</item>
</node1>
```

I would like this to output the following using an XPath expression:

```
hello, world
```

Is this possible with XPath 1.0? I have been looking around but unable to find anything.

Thanks,
Cinegod

Comment: XPath 1.0 or 2.0? Also, do you really want to limit discussion to XPath, or can you bring in a context environment like XSLT or .NET?

Comment: Good point. I was interested in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 you can do that by using `concat()`, e.g.:

```
concat(node1/item[1], ", ", node1/item[2])
```

Answer (score 11):

XPath 2.0 can do `string-join(/node1/item, ', ')`. With XPath 1.0 you can't do that, you would need to use a host language like XSLT or a procedural language exposing an XPath API to iterate over nodes and concatenate values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Martin!